# Access Javascript Object Property Issue

Tags: javascript, object, angularjs, properties

I'm having issues accessing properties of a very simple object. As a novice programmer I suspect I have a simple misunderstanding of what exactly I'm working with.

Here is the code that is executing:

```
    console.log(content);
    console.log(content.title);
    for (x in content){
        console.log(content[x])
    }
```

And here is the console response:

```
{"title":"test","description":"test"}
undefined
{
"
t
i
t
l
e
"
:
"
t
e
s
t
"
,
"
d
e
s
c
r
i
p
t
i
o
n
"
:
"
t
e
s
t
"

}
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

*edit*

The content object is being sent to the server via angular.js $http service as follows:

```
$http({
            method:'post',
            url:"/create/createContent",
            params:{content:$scope.content}
        }).
```

It seems the service moves the data in the JSON format.

Thanks everyone for the help! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you please include how you've expressed your object?

Comment: Where do you set `content`? Looks like it might be a string not an object. Also `for...in` is often more trouble that it's worth.

Comment: I define content as an empty object (content = {}) which is added do dynamically based on user input (using angular.js). I think I must accidently be converting it to a string when it is sent to the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like `content` is in fact a string and you are simply iterating over the characters in the string. Try this and see if it gives you what you want:

```
var contentJson = JSON.parse(content);
for (var x in contentJson) {
    console.log(contentJson[x]);
}
```

This will parse the `content` string into the appropriate JavaScript object and you should be able to access its properties.

Answer (score 3):

Looks to me like the problem is how you are defining `content`.  Are you doing this?

```
content = '{"title":"test","description":"test"}';
```

or are you doing this?

```
content = {"title":"test","description":"test"};
```

Note: the first one has the entire thing wrapped in single quotes while the second has none.

Comment: +1 This is also a good answer if you have control over the `content` variable's definition. No need to `JSON.parse` if you are defining the variable in your own code.

Answer (score 2):

Your object content is in JSON string form.  Do this and you will get your desired results:

```
content = JSON.parse(content);
console.log(content);
console.log(content.title);
for (x in content){
    console.log(content[x])
}
```

The way you can tell you are in JSON format is because of the quotations around the key values.  If you were in object format, you wouldn't see the quotes.

See the difference below:

JSON string when output to console {"key1":1,"key2":"two"}

Object when output to console {key:1,key2:"two"}